# Is there a way to use python 3.9 to emulate default rng from python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I have a program which is implemented in Python 2.7 that I want to migrate to Python 3.9.

I want to use regression testing to check if the migration is successful and confirm that the new version is performing the same calculation as the old version.

However...

The program uses `random.Random(seed)` which the previous developer unwisely decided to seed with floating point numbers.

The code ports to python 3.9 easily but unfortunately it produces different random numbers (apart from instances where the float happens to be an integer). Fiddling around with the generators it looks like this is a consequence of the two versions using a different hash() method. It is not a consequence of changes in float point representation.

Is there a way to generate the same set of random numbers in Python 3.9 that would have been generated by that particular line of code in Python 2.7? i.e. How can I generate the result that legacy code `random.Random(1.01)` would produce without using a legacy interpreter?

Comment: There have been plenty more changes than just the seeding algorithm. Python's default `random` module provides very few cross-version reproducibility guarantees.

Comment: @user2357112 fair comment - - some quick testing suggested that it was reproducing values when seeded with small-ish integers (only tested to around 2000). As you say there are no guarantees, but it appears to be the case that the random module uses the same version of the MT algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code ports to python 3.9 easily but unfortunately it produces different random numbers (apart from instances where the float happens to be an integer). Fiddling around with the generators it looks like this is a consequence of the two versions using a different hash() method.

If you read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.18/Objects/object.c#L1020-L1083) of Python 2.7, you can see how floating point hashing is implemented.

Once you have the C implementation, you can translate that into Python. I've simplified some details, such as not implementing integer hashing.

```
import math


def hash_double_version_27(v):
    fractpart, intpart = math.modf(v)
    if fractpart == 0:
        raise Exception("hash for exact integer values not implemented")
    v, expo = math.frexp(v)
    v *= 2147483648.0
    hipart = int(v)
    v = (v - hipart) * 2147483648.0
    x = hipart + int(v) + (expo << 15)
    if x == -1:
        x = -2
    return x
```

I tested this by generating a few thousand random floating point numbers, and testing it against a copy of Python 2.7.18.

To use this with the random number generator, you can pass the resulting integer to `random.Random()`, and it will not hash it any further. There is a subtlety around how negative numbers are handled, however: if you pass in a negative integer, it will get rid of the negative by taking the absolute value of the number. However, if it hashes an object and that results in a negative number, it casts the signed integer into an unsigned integer.

Here's how to convert the negative integer in the same manner as [the C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.18/Modules/_randommodule.c#L231). (Note that the comment there is incorrect - absolute value is not used for values from object hashing.)

```py
import random

def cast_hash_to_unsigned(integer, bits):
    if integer < 0:
        integer += 1 << bits
    return integer


def get_rand_object(f):
    float_hash = hash_double_version_27(f)
    float_hash = cast_hash_to_unsigned(float_hash, 64)
    rng = random.Random(float_hash)
    return rng
```

Similarly, I checked a few thousand generated values from this against Python 2.7.18, and it matched the cases I checked.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer with lots of useful learning points (for me). Inspecting the underlying C code is something I hadn't considered - will keep that trick handy for the future.